# Why does a windows Batch File work in the traditional windows console host but throws an error in the new windows terminal

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, terminal, batch

I am able to run a simple **batch file** in the old traditional **windows console host** (CMD) but when running it in the new **windows terminal** it throws an error and fails.

[image: The two different command lines]

**Various errors that are thrown:**

[image: err1]
[image: err2]
[image: err3]

I have tried changing the default command line to **cmd**/**powershell** in the new **terminal** but that did not have any effect. I think that the error is related to a path not being found when running the **bat** file in the new **terminal** although I am not sure why that would be the case.

**Source Code of Bat File:**

```
@echo off

echo kill current binaries

cmd /c TASKKILL /F /IM nginx* > nul 2> nul
cmd /c TASKKILL /F /IM V-* > nul 2> nul


set DIR=binaries
PUSHD %DIR%
cd

FOR %%F IN (
    V-DBV_*.exe
    ) DO start /w /b %%F

FOR %%F IN (
    V-FC_*.exe
    V-AGS_*.exe
    V-T4CA_*.exe
    V-FIO_*.exe
    ) DO start /b %%F > NUL

POPD
start /b nginx\nginx -c conf\nginx_generic_test.conf -p .\nginx
echo "test started"
```

Even though errors are thrown in relation to **nginx**, the issue as far as I can tell has nothing to do with **nginx** since the **bat** file is executed perfectly fine in the traditional **windows console host**.

If anyone has a suggestion or a solution for this issue, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing "nginx*" in double-quotes, and/or adding the full process name, *nginx.exe*? Apparently, PowerShell finds **package** info for the configuration file before the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Your `Terminal` is invoking `cmd.exe` (command interpreter) to execute the instructions from your `file.bat`, and as the `cmd.exe` path is `C:\Windows\System32`, it doesn't find your folder there to proceed with the execution of the executable `nginx` in a `\binary` and/or `\nginx`  subfolders.

---

- Assuming your bat starts in the same root folder where you have a subfolder `binaries`, use relative path `%~dp0` in your `pushd` (and in `start /d "D:\full\path`) command, otherwise specify the full path:

```bat
@ECHO OFF


PUSHD "%~pd0binaries"
ECHO."%CD%"

ECHO kill current binaries

FOR %%F IN (
    nginx*.exe
    V-*.exe
    ) DO TASKKILL /f /im "%%~F" > nul 2> nul

FOR %%F IN (
    V-DBV_*.exe
    ) DO START "" /w /b "%%~F"

FOR %%F IN (
    V-FC_*.exe
    V-AGS_*.exe
    V-T4CA_*.exe
    V-FIO_*.exe
    ) DO START "" /b "%%~F" > nul

POPD
START "" /b /d "%~pd0nginx" nginx.exe -c "%~pd0nginx\conf\nginx_generic_test.conf" -p "%~pd0nginx"
ECHO "test started"
```

---

- About `START /D`:

```bat
Start an application and specify where files will be saved (Working Directory):

 
START /D C:\Documents\ /MAX "Maximised Notes" notepad.exe
```

---

- About `%~dp0`

See [What does `%~dp0` mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290765/8177207)

---

- About `set DIR=binaries` and `PUSHD %DIR%`

You are not using the `DIR` variable and you can directly use the path in your `pushd`command, besides you don't even need this variable in the posted commands: `PUSHD "%~pd0binaries"`

Comment: I have tested the binary with your code snippet and now it throws no errors, but it closes on launch. If I run the binary as administrator, it works as usual, although it then runs the binary in the standard command prompt (instead of the default windows terminal).